# How to do "where not exists" type filtering in Kibana/ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using ELK to create dashboards from my log files. I have a log file with entries that contain an id value and a "success"/"failure" value, displaying whether an operation with a given id succeeded or failed. Each operation/id can fail an unlimited number of times and succeed at most once. In my Kibana dashboard I want to display the count of log entries with a "failure" value for each operation id, but I want to filter out cases where a "success" log entry for the id exists. i.e. I am only interested in operations that never succeeded. Any hints for tricks that would achieve this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is easy in Kibana 5 search bar. Just add a filter

```
!(_exists_:"your_variable")
```

you can toggle the filter or write the inverse query as

```
_exists_:"your_variable"
```

---

In Kibana 4 and Kibana 3 you can use this query which is now deprecated

```
_missing_:"your_variable"
```

---

**NOTE:** In Elasticsearch 7.x, Kibana now has a pull down to select KQL or Lucene style queries in the search bar. Be mindful that syntax such as `_exists_:FIELD` is a Lucene syntax and you need to set the pulldown accordingly.

Comment: for reference, here is the link to where the \_ notation for "exists" and "missing" is documented: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names

Comment: `_missing_` doesn't seem to be present in ElasticSearch 5.0 any more. `!(_exists_:"field")` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating the query syntax @Fedearne !

Comment: note: In 7.x I had to put `(!_exists_:"your_variable")` in parenthesis when an `OR` was present

Answer (score 30):

In newer ELK versions (I think after Elasticsearch 6) you should use `field:*` to check if the field exist and `not field:*` to check if it's missing.

elastic search reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards

Comment: thanks! btw, in Kibana search line, it works only with upper case "NOT" for me

Answer (score 13):

`! (_exists_:NAME)` is not working for me. I use suggestion from:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-5-0-0--missing--is-not-working-anymore/64336

```
NOT _exists_:NAME
```

**UPDATE** The problem I faced is that ES syntax forbids spaces after negation operators. Use one of:

```
NOT _exists_:FIELD
!_exists_:FIELD
-_exists_:FIELD
```

Check tutorial: https://www.timroes.de/2016/05/29/elasticsearch-kibana-queries-in-depth-tutorial/

---

**NOTE:** In Elasticsearch 7.x, Kibana now has a pull down to select KQL or Lucene style queries in the search bar. Be mindful that syntax such as `_exists_:FIELD` is a Lucene syntax and you need to set the pulldown accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of Kibana the default language is now **KQL** (Kibana Query Language) not Lucene anymore. So most answers here are outdated. The query if a field exists is the following:

```
your_variable:*
```

and to answer your question you can just negate that:

```
not your_variable:*
```

You can find more documation on here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.15/kuery-query.html

You can also toggle back to Lucene if you click on that button inside the search field but in my opinion the new language is way easier to use:
[image]

Answer (score -4):

One option would be to create an own query for this criteria in Kibana. Then just have your panel that does the counting just to use this query.

```
value:failure
```

More information here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Comment: I can see only options for selecting a document based on its content there, whereas I am looking for a solution that selects documents based on the content of other documents, i.e. an SQL "not exists" / "not in" style query. Did I miss something?

Comment: Would not the following work for you:  
1. In Kibana, create a new query with the criteria to get log entries. In your case just with value:failure is probably enough if the data is on the same field, but this would work with boolean operators such as NOT as well.  
2. Add a new Panel in Kibana, simple terms based panel should do. For the parameters Field put your ID that you want to count, then on the queries dropdown select Selected and just highlight the query you did on the previous step.

Comment: The problem is filtering by sql "not exists" style: I want to count only entries with value=failure when no entry with value=success for the same id exists.

Comment: OK then the above wont work sorry. If you have any another field that indicates the successful log entry you can exclude this from the query, then the above should work.  Also, Kibana 4 supports aggregation now, which might allow you to do more advanced unique counts that you are after.