# How to visualize NULL values in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Doc stored in ES index is like this:

```
{
   "product_id": "something_unique",
   "price": 25
}
```

The price section can also be `null` at times. (This is just as assumed db structure, as I don't want to list all the actual attributes which are being used in elasticsearch).

Now when I try to visualize this in Kibana I get results like this:

[image]

The visualized data is only for 3 entries whereas we have data for 11 products in the ES system. The other 8 entries have price as null. I want to showcase this info in kibana graph so that the admin can take proper action for this. 
So, is there any way `I can show the details of docs which have price as null` ?

I am new to Elasticsearch and couldn't find solution to this anywhere else therefore posting it here. Please don't come up with comments like "null values are not supposed to be visualized , I have implemented the /_xpack/sql api but its not very handy".

I am using Elasticsearch 6.5

Comment: "Add a filter" didnot help you?

Comment: @LeBigCat With filters kibana will visualize null values in a separate graph but, i need to show the null info within the same graph.

Comment: @bhatman Did you manage to maje this work?

Comment: Okay I managed to do it thanks to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30736532/6175451