# Group Grafana chart by presence of a datetime field with Elasticsearch datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have an Elasticsearch datasource with a field called `aborted_at`. It’s an ISO-8601 timestamp, and it is only present for some records.

I want to create a bar chart, stacked to 100%, that shows the proportion of finished and aborted records over time.

My query is a simple filter:

```
type.keyword = "$measurement_type"
```

and I’ve set my grouping to terms and date histogram. But I can only group by the actual values of `aborted_at`:

[image]

I would like to be able to group by (pseudocode) `empty(aborted_at)` or whatever possible solution to turn the field into a binary one (i.e., present or not).

I can get this relatively easily within Kibana’s Lens visualization:

[image]

… but I don't see how to do that with Grafana's Elasticsearch datasource queries.

<sub>*This is a cross-post from the [Grafana discussion board](https://community.grafana.com/t/group-by-presence-of-a-datetime-field-with-elasticsearch-datasource/85319/1). I will keep both posts updated when a solution is found.*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your panel create two queries:

- `type.keyword: "$measurement_type" AND (_exists_:"aborted_at")` with alias Aborted,
- `type.keyword: "$measurement_type" AND !(_exists_:"aborted_at")` with alias finished.

Both with `Metric(1)` `Count`. Group by `Date Histogram`; `aborted_at` for the first one, field containing finish date for second one.

Then in Panel options > Bar chart > Staking select 100%.

In the result you'll get something like
[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks! Where can I find documentation for `_exists_`? I have never seen that. [These docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/elasticsearch/query-editor/) don't seem to apply here.

Comment: @slhck, truth be told - I have no idea: I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30736532/21363224). It is Lucene's (or Elastic's, or something of this matter) function, and I'm not familiar: I'm here because I know Grafana). Your link - is just a description on how Lucene queries could be used in Grafana, not a fully fledged reference for Lucene.

Comment: I found out that this is the same as writing `*`, e.g. `aborted_at:*` — must be a legacy function.